# System does not boot automatically

Tags: grub2, kernel

I have a standard 16.04 server system. 
The problem is that if I let the machine to boot on its own, it fails with kernel panic `unable to mount root fs on unknown-block`, but if I hold left shift and after grub menu is up simply push 'enter' key the system boots fine. 
If I enter edit mode and exit without changes, I get kernel panic `unable to mount root fs on unknown-block`
Grub config was generated with `grub-update`, no new drives or unusual hardware used.

I have other systems configured same way, they all boot fine.

What might the problem be?

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet nomdmonddf nomdmonisw scsi_mod.use_blk_mq=1"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=text
```